# How to add padding to the Symfony console command?

Tags: console, command, output, symfony

Developers, hi!

I want to output messages in my console command looks as it is implemented in the Doctrine console commands:
[image]

I tried to add line breaks to console messages using PHP_EOL as follows:

```
$output->writeln('<bg=green>' . PHP_EOL. 'The statistics of ' . $affiliateProgramName . ' for period from ' .
    $beginningDate->format('Y-m-d') . ' to ' . $endDate->format('Y-m-d') . ' has been downloaded.' . PHP_EOL . '</>');
```

The result can be seen in the picture:
[image]

The background stretched to the full width of the console, and I have not get padding like in the Doctrine commands.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Six03, thanks for the tip! Of course, I can't consider it as a sufficient answer, but it helped me find all necessary information.

Firstly you must declare the helper with the context 'formatter' as a property of a ContainerAwareCommand object:

```
$formatter = $this->getHelper('formatter');
```

Then you must declare the array with the content that will be displayed in the console. Every element of array is a new line of your message. Next, you need to add your message and your style to the block of declared 'formatter' like this:

```
$infoMessage = array('INFO:', 'Date interval is ' . $interval->format('%a') . ' days.');
$formattedInfoBlock = $formatter->formatBlock($infoMessage, 'info', TRUE);
```

If you pass true as third parameter, the block will be formatted with more padding (one blank line above and below the messages and 2 spaces on the left and right). ([Formatter Helper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/formatterhelper.html))

And now all that you should perform is to pass your block with the required design to 'output' object:

```
$output->writeln($formattedInfoBlock);
```

Here is the whole code step by step:

```
/**
 * Setting the console styles
 *
 * 'INFO' style
 */
$infoStyle = new OutputFormatterStyle('white', 'blue');
$output->getFormatter()->setStyle('info', $infoStyle);

/**
 * 'SUCCESS' style
 */
$successStyle = new OutputFormatterStyle('white', 'green');
$output->getFormatter()->setStyle('success', $successStyle);

/**
 * Declaring the formatter
 */
$formatter = $this->getHelper('formatter');

/**
 * The output to the console
 */
$infoMessage = array('INFO:', 'Date interval is ' . $interval->format('%a') . ' days.');
$formattedInfoBlock = $formatter->formatBlock($infoMessage, 'info', TRUE);
$output->writeln($formattedInfoBlock);
```

Now messages in my commands have an appropriate kind.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this, perhaps this is what you're looking for;

```
/**
 * Formats a message as a block of text.
 *
 * @param string|array $messages The message to write in the block
 * @param string|null  $type     The block type (added in [] on first line)
 * @param string|null  $style    The style to apply to the whole block
 * @param string       $prefix   The prefix for the block
 * @param bool         $padding  Whether to add vertical padding
 */
public function block($messages, $type = null, $style = null, $prefix = ' ', $padding = false)
{
    $messages = is_array($messages) ? array_values($messages) : array($messages);
    $this->autoPrependBlock();
    $this->writeln($this->createBlock($messages, $type, $style, $prefix, $padding, true));
    $this->newLine();
}
```

[You can find the entire file here.](https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Style/SymfonyStyle.php)